# Nativescript JS send URLSearchParams into POST request

Tags: javascript, api, post, request, nativescript

I want to send data to an API not with JSON but with x-www-form-urlencoded (URLSearchParams).

I tried with this code but the data is not received correctly by the API.

```
return fetchModule.fetch(config.apiUrl + "auth/register",
        {
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "username": viewModel.get("username"),
                "firstname": viewModel.get("firstname"),
                "lastname": viewModel.get("lastname"),
                "email": viewModel.get("email"),
                "password": viewModel.get("password")
            }),
            method: "POST",
            headers:{
                "content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
        }).then(handleErrors);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the `JSON.stringify` for a `URLSearchParams` and remove the content-type header, fetch will automatically add the correct content-type when it detects URLSearchParams as a body

```
return fetchModule.fetch(config.apiUrl + "auth/register", {
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    "username": viewModel.get("username"),
    "firstname": viewModel.get("firstname"),
    "lastname": viewModel.get("lastname"),
    "email": viewModel.get("email"),
    "password": viewModel.get("password")
  }),
  method: "POST"
}).then(handleErrors);
```

Comment: I tried but I have an error "URLSearchParams is not defined"

Comment: hmm, are u using IE?

Comment: No nativescript with JS for mobile app

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the {N} runtime has access to `URLSearchParams` class, it's browser specific.

You could achieve the same with a simple loop through keys in object,

```
var data = {
 "username": viewModel.get("username"),
 "firstname": viewModel.get("firstname"),
 "lastname": viewModel.get("lastname"),
 "email": viewModel.get("email"),
 "password": viewModel.get("password")
};
var endocedStr = "";
for (var prop in data) {
  if(endocedStr) {
    endocedStr += "&";
  } 
  endocedStr += prop + "=" + data[prop];
}
return fetchModule.fetch(config.apiUrl + "auth/register", {
  body: endocedStr
  method: "POST"
}).then(handleErrors);
```